# How do I add image preview to this jquery script?

Tags: jquery, image, hover, preview

Ive tried several different ways to add an image hover preview option to the file manager/file upload script I use.

Ill post my scripts below. Any help is appreciated.

```
$(function($){
var optionDefaults = {
    path            : '',
    upload          : false,
    readonly        : false,
    fixedPath       : false,

    baseClass       : 'fmBase',
    folderClass     : 'fmFolder',
    trashClass      : 'fmTrash',
    backClass       : 'fmBack',
    loadingClass    : 'fmLoading',

    highlightClass  : 'ui-state-highlight',
    hoverClass      : 'ui-state-active'
};

$.fn.fileManager = function(settings, pluploadOptions) {
    var mbOptions = $.extend({}, optionDefaults, settings);
    if (!mbOptions.ajaxPath) {
        alert('ajaxPath not specified'); return;
    }
    if (mbOptions.fixedPath) mbOptions.path = mbOptions.fixedPath;

    pluploadOptions = $.extend({url:mbOptions.ajaxPath,runtimes:'html5,html4'}, pluploadOptions);

    var query = $.extend({},{path:mbOptions.path},mbOptions.get);
    this.each(function () { // swap with getJSON so not duplicating ajax
        var $sel = $(this);
        $.getJSON(mbOptions.ajaxPath, query, function(data, status) {
            $sel.data('result',data);
            $sel.data('options',mbOptions);
            if (status != "success") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: "+status;
            }
            // process response
            $sel.empty();

            if (!mbOptions.readonly) {
                $sel.append('<div class="path"><b>URL Path:</b> '+data.rootPath+data.path+'</div>');
                if (data.path && !mbOptions.fixedPath) DrawItem($sel,{path:'..',title:'...',type:3});
                DrawItem($sel,{path:'',title:'',type:2});
            }
            if ($(data.files).length == 0) {
              $sel.append('<div style="font-size:12px; margin: 35px 0 0 15px;">No files in this folder</div>');
            }
            $(data.files).each(function () {
                DrawItem($sel,this);
            });
            $sel.append('<div style="clear:both"></div>');
            if (!mbOptions.readonly)
                $sel.append($('<div style="margin:5px">New Folder</div>').button().bind('click',NewFolder));
            if (mbOptions.upload) {
                var ul = $('<div></div>').hide();
                $sel.append($('<div style="margin:5px">Upload Files</div>').button().bind('click',{container:ul},UploadFiles));
                $sel.append(ul);
            }

            // end processing

            $('.'+mbOptions.baseClass,$sel).disableSelection();//bind('selectstart',function () { return false; });
            $('.'+mbOptions.folderClass,$sel).bind('dblclick',ItemDblClick);
            $('.'+mbOptions.backClass,$sel).bind('dblclick',ItemDblClickBack);
        });

        function UploadFiles(event) {
            $(event.data.container).toggle();
            if (plupload && pluploadOptions) {
                if (!$(event.data.container).pluploadQueue) {
                    $(event.data.container).html('Must install Plupload jquery plugin.'); return;
                }
                var opts = pluploadOptions;
                opts.url = opts.url+ (opts.url.indexOf('?') < 0 ? '?' : '&') +'path='+$sel.data('result').path;
                $(event.data.container).pluploadQueue(opts);
                $(event.data.container).pluploadQueue().bind('FileUploaded',function (uploader,file,response) {
                    if (uploader.total.queued == 0) {
                        RefreshView($sel);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $(event.data.container).html('Must install Plupload.');
            }
        }
        function NewFolder() {
            var path = prompt('Enter Folder Name:');
            if (!path) return;
            if ($sel.data('result').path) path = $sel.data('result').path + '/' + path;
            ReloadFolder($sel, path);
        }
    });


    function FileDropped(event,ui) {
        var from = $(ui.draggable);
        var to = $(this);

        if ($(this).hasClass(mbOptions.trashClass)) {
            if (confirm('Delete "'+from.data('item').title+'"?')) {
                ajaxData = {path:mbOptions.path,'delete':from.data('item').path};
                $.ajax({url:mbOptions.ajaxPath,data:ajaxData,dataType:'script',complete:function() {
                    RefreshView(from.data('item').target);
                }});
            }
        } else {
            return Rename(from.data('item').target,from.data('item').path,to.data('item').path+'/'+from.data('item').path);
        }
    };
    function Rename(view,from,to) {
        ajaxData = {path:mbOptions.path,mFrom:from,mTo:to};
        $.ajax({url:mbOptions.ajaxPath,data:ajaxData,dataType:'script',complete:function() {
            RefreshView(view);
        }});
    }
    function ItemDblClick() {
        var item = $(this).data('item');
        if (item.type != ICONTYPE_FOLDER) return;
        var path = item.path;
        if (item.target.data('result').path) path = item.target.data('result').path + '/' + path;
        ReloadFolder(item.target,path);
    }
    function ItemDblClickBack() {
        var item = $(this).data('item');
        if (item.type != ICONTYPE_BACK) return;
        var path = item.path;
        if (item.target.data('result').path) path = item.target.data('result').path + '/' + path;
        ReloadFolder(item.target,path);
    }
    function RefreshView(target) {
        ReloadFolder(target,target.data('result').path);
    }
    function ReloadFolder(target,path) {
        target.fileManager($.extend({},mbOptions,{path:path}),pluploadOptions);
    };

    var ICONTYPE_FILE = 0;
    var ICONTYPE_FOLDER = 1;
    var ICONTYPE_TRASH = 2;
    var ICONTYPE_BACK = 3;
    function DrawItem(target, item) {
        if (item.type == ICONTYPE_FOLDER && mbOptions.fixedPath) return;

        item.target = $(target);
        item.fullPath = item.target.data('result').rootPath + item.target.data('result').path + '/' + item.path;
        var icon = $('<div title="'+item.title+'"></div>');
        icon.data('item',item);
        icon.addClass(mbOptions.baseClass);

        // set classes
        if (item.type == ICONTYPE_FOLDER)
            icon.addClass(mbOptions.folderClass);
        else if (item.type == ICONTYPE_TRASH)
            icon.addClass(mbOptions.trashClass);
        else if (item.type == ICONTYPE_BACK)
            icon.addClass(mbOptions.backClass);

        // set draggables
        if (!mbOptions.readonly) {
            if (item.type == ICONTYPE_FOLDER || item.type == ICONTYPE_TRASH)
                icon.droppable({tolerance:'intersect',accept:'.'+mbOptions.baseClass,drop:FileDropped,hoverClass:mbOptions.hoverClass,activeClass:mbOptions.highlightClass});
            if (item.type != ICONTYPE_TRASH && item.path != '..')
                icon.draggable({stack:'files',revert:true,zIndex:1000,opacity:0.5,scroll:false});
        }

        if (item.type == ICONTYPE_FILE && item.path.search(/.jpeg|.jpg|.png|.gif|.tif|.tiff/i) > -1) {
            icon.css('background-image','none');
            icon.append('<img style="width:100%;height:100%" src="'+item.fullPath+'">');
        }

        // events
        if (mbOptions.events) {
            $.each(mbOptions.events,function (index,value) {
                icon.bind(index, value);
            });
        }
        icon.data('result',target.data('result'));

        target.append(icon);
        if (!item.path) return;

        //if (mbOptions.readonly) return;

        var ext = item.path.match(/\.[^.\b]*$/i);
        if (ext) ext = ext[0];
        else ext = '';
        var basename = item.path.replace(ext,'');

        var renamebox = $('<input style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px" type="text">')
            .bind('focus',function() { $(this).val(basename); })
            .bind('blur',function() { $(this).hide(); if (item.path == $(this).val()+ext) return; Rename(item.target,item.path,$(this).val()+ext); })
            .bind('keydown',function(event) { if (event.keyCode == '13' || event.keyCode == '27') $(this).blur(); })
            .hide()
            .appendTo(icon);
        var label = $('<div class="label">'+item.title+'</div>')
            .prependTo(icon)//.bind('dblclick',function() {return false;})
            .bind('click',function () {
                if (!mbOptions.readonly) {
                    renamebox.show().focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    return $(this);
};
```

})(jQuery);

Heres the image preview script:

```
this.imagePreview = function(){ 
/* CONFIG */

    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 30;

    // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
    // you might want to adjust to get the right result

/* END CONFIG */
$("a.preview").hover(function(e){
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";    
    var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
    $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");                        
},
function(){
    this.title = this.t;    
    $("#preview").remove();
}); 
$("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});         
};// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});
```

The problem Im having is I have to write the preview part into the file manager part. The preview cant operate as a separate script because the file manager script writes everything on the fly with json/ajax. FYI, the preview script works fine in my test page when used by itself. Hopefully this clarifies my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. What Ive learned from researching jquery is that hover is a function to facilitate mouseenter and mouseleave. So instead of trying to bind a hover, bind the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Below is the before and after corrected code so you can see my solution.

**BEFORE**

```
if (item.type == ICONTYPE_FILE && item.path.search(/.jpeg|.jpg|.png|.gif|.tif|.tiff/i) > -1) {
        icon.css('background-image','none');
        icon.append('<img style="width:100%;height:100%" src="'+item.fullPath+'">');
    }
```

**AFTER**

```
if (item.type == ICONTYPE_FILE && item.path.search(/.jpeg|.jpg|.png|.gif|.tif|.tiff/i) > -1) {
            xOffset = 10;
            yOffset = 30; // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
            icon.css('background-image','none');
            icon.append($('<img style="width:100%;height:100%" src="'+item.fullPath+'">').bind({
                mouseenter: function(e) {
                // Hover event handler
                $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+item.fullPath+"' alt='Image preview' /></p>");                                
                $("#preview")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn("fast");
                },
                mouseleave: function(e) {
                // Hover event handler
                $("#preview").remove();
                }
            }));
        }
```

Side Note: You'll need to add the following css to either one of your css files or the page your using to make it work.

**NEEDED CSS**

```
#preview{
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #ccc;
background:#e6e6e6;
padding:5px;
display:none;
color:#fff;
}
```